# Bracha: Dried tomato Wraps

Tags: blessing, food, hamotzi-beracha

What Bracha do you make on a "dried tomato wrap"? It's a ready made wrap and the ingredients just say dried tomato wrap in addition to the fillers, vegetables and some mayonnaise.

Comment: Hi Shaye M. Thanks for bringing your question to Mi Yodeya, but please proceed with caution and consultation of a competent authority rather than trusting any practical advice you receive to questions of law here.

Comment: Is the wrap itself made out of dried tomatoes? Or its a standard wrap filled with amongst other items, dried tomatoes?

Comment: @user6591 I'm pretty sure he means that part of the ingredients in the wrap (i.e., the "shell") includes dried tomatoes. It seems that "fancy" ingredient wraps are becoming trendy. To me, this would be in the same category as spinach wraps.

Comment: @DanF I would tend to agree with you, but there is some room left to wonder.

Comment: Given the "dried tomato wrap, do you mean Unfilled: ha'adamh or shehakol, Filled: whatever is inside the filling is now ikor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [OU brachot site](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/#baked), if you eat a plain wrap, it is mezonot, because this is not the normal way people eat wraps. However, if it is filled, one says, "hamotzi".

Comment: The reason there to make a mezonos on a plain wrap "If one were to eat a plain wrap (unfilled) then it would be mezonos. Because it is not the way people eat this, this is a chisaron in the tzuras hapas. But if one were to eat a filled wrap with tuna or cheese etc… then the proper beracha would be hamotzi". Where do we find this klal?

Comment: @user6591 needs further research. Perhaps, ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @sabbahillel I'm not following your question. The wrap itself is mainly wheat. It is generally used as a sandwich making it hamotzi. Plain, it would be mezonot because of the rule the OU site lists. I'm not sure why that rule applies to wraps, though. Either way, I'mnot following why it would be adama. A dried tomato wrap has tomato as a minority ingredient, from what I have seen and read on most brands' ingredients.

Comment: OK From calling it a "dried tomato wrap", I thought that meant it had been made out of dried tomato. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @sabbahillel Not a problem. I admit that the question is vague, but my understanding is that it's similar to this product: http://www.flatoutbread.com/products/flatout-wraps/flatout-traditional/sundried-tomato/ You can see that sundried tomato comprises less than 2% of the ingredients, so this is clearly "bread".